# NPM vulnerabilities - requires manual review

Tags: node.js, npm, node-http-proxy

Whilst starting a new project and running `npm install` I got a couple of vulnerabilities w.r.t http and https proxy. Running `npm audit fix` doesn't appear to fix them.

I have also tried manually updating to the latest version available such as `npm install https-proxy-agent@2.2.1` which successfully adds package (with no repo field warning) yet when i run npm audit the 2 vulnerabilities persist. Is this potentially down to multiple copies of http-proxy?

Many thanks in advance

[image: npm vunerabilities]

Comment: I've gotten similar warnings - and experienced similar results - with projects completely unrelated to http-proxy-agent.  I'm curious what responses you get :)

Comment: Which theme you are using in your terminal? Looks osum!

Answer (score 1):

The warnings about the vulnerabilities are caused by the deprecated `typings` package because it has a dependency on `popsicle-proxy-agent` which uses an old version of `https-proxy-agent` (The warnings give you those information under the `Dependency of` and `Path` labels). Remove the **deprecated** package and install your typings via `npm install @types/<package>`.